# Unable to post comment using Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am playing around with the Facebook API, trying to comment on items in my news feed. I am using the Graph API explorer to run these tests.

For example, a friend on Facebook has shared a link. I can see the ID of the object in the URL:

`https://www.facebook.com/########/posts/362739827093735`

If I then try to comment on this item ID using the Graph API explorer, posting to:

`https://graph.facebook.com/362739827093735/comments`

I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Cannot access object_id: 362739827093735", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why I'm receiving this error as I am sure that I have set the correct permissions in the API explorer:

[image: Permissions]

I have tried this on various items in my news feed and most of them have this issue. Can anybody tell me why?

**Update:**

Right, so if I use the author ID along with the fbid, like so:

`https://graph.facebook.com/100000383678807_362739827093735/comments`

I move on to this error (despite having all the right permissions!):

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#210) User not visible", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 210
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to access that post via Graph API by `https://graph.facebook.com/362739827093735`? It looks like this post privacy settings is restricted...

Comment: I can do a GET request on it and it retrieves the data fine.

Comment: Are you sure you are even able to post normally (via UI) on this post? If you can post normally, and you are sending the `publish_stream` permissions then there should not be any problems.

Comment: object_id= id+_+story_fbid
ex: facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=444318302271368&id=100000796055747&_rdr
object_id= 100000796055747_444318302271368